# Fractional ideals of localizations are all induced by the fractional ideals of the base ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $P$ be a non-zero prime ideal of $R$. Let $I$ be a fractional ideal of $R_P$.

Then, how do I prove that there exists a fractional ideal $J$ of $R$ such that $I=JR_P$?

I could prove this by additionally assuming $R$ is Noetherian, but I am not sure how to prove this when $R$ is just an integral domain.

Comment: Noetherianness of $R$ is not necessary: it suffices that $I$ be a finitely generated fractional ideal of $R_{\mathfrak p}$.

Comment: @Bernard Yes sure, it should be. However, it is an exercise to prove this without assuming any finitely generated condition. (Dummit &Foote - Algebra p.773 exercise 3)

Comment: I only made a comment for the most obvious part… What's your definition of a fractional ideal?

Comment: An $R$-submodule $I$ of $Quot(R)$ such that there exists $d\in R\setminus\{0\}$ such that $dI\subset R$ is said to be a fractiona ideal of $R$.

Comment: We agree on the definition. Unfortunately, I can see no reason * a priori* why it should be true for a non-finitely generated fractional ideal (which does not mean it isn't true!).